# Are there any issues with storing ME storage devices in ME storage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-applied-energistics

I haven't tried it because I'm afraid this kind of recursive storage might break something, but is there anything that could happen if I fully load a storage device using an ME I/O, then store the storage device into the ME network using access terminal?

If there's nothing wrong with doing this, then isn't this like a bug, since how did the data in the storage get compressed to a single item/type?

Comment: I want to say that it works because it works in your inventory. It will take up more space on the drive, since they won't stack, but it should retain all information. I can't confirm this right now, though.

Comment: I don't think you can load the storage device in the first place.

Comment: Hopefully it doesn't result in a bag-of-holding-inside-a-bag-of-holding type situation.

Comment: @gnovice So you're saying experiments should be conducted in a disposable world you don't mind getting slightly exploded? Good advice. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You explode when that happens?

Comment: @jeffreylin In D&D, a bag of holding will do bad things when another one is put inside. I don't recall what "bad things" are in the current edition, but exploding was definitely in a previous edition. And exploding is the kind of thing tech mod authors do like to use as a disincentive for abusing the machines…

Comment: I know that empty storage can definitely be held in an ME network, since I autocraft mine. Not sure about full ones.

Comment: Please rewrite the question to not use acronyms used by the community of the game so the general gaming community can read the question as well.

Comment: @James Really? Those are the names of the involved items an blocks.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie ME doesn't stand for anything?

Comment: @James Sure it does. But the in-game items use the acronym, so general gamers who are not players of this game will have *less* success understanding the question via search engines if it was spelled out. It's not in-community jargon as you assume. Most players don't even know what it stands for—I'd have to look it up.

Comment: @James If you're curious, you can read about [the mod here](http://ae-mod.info/ME-Storage-and-Automation/). Even its documentation uses "ME" everywhere, and explains the meaning only once. Apparently it means "Matter Energy". This fact doesn't actually appear in the game, so it's just a bit of trivia.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

When I was moving my base (I had an ME network), everything went into my storage devices. I then tried to move all my storage devices into a storage device, it just wouldn't place it into the network. So no, nothing bad happens if you try, but it doesn't let you either.